# error in sql syntax vb.net using delete code

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I don't know what seems to be the problem here but I cant delete using this code
it shows an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* From borrowers where id =17' at line 1

```vb
Try

    QueryConnect = "DELETE * From borrowers Where ID=@BID"
    CommandConnect = New MySqlCommand(QueryConnect, DataConnection)

    CommandConnect.Parameters.Add("@BID", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = BIDLabel.Text

    MyDataConnect = CommandConnect.ExecuteReader

    MessageBox.Show("Borrower Deleted Successfully", LoginUI.BrandMsgBox, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)

    MyDataConnect.Close()

    'Refresh Borrowers List
    'GetBorrowersList()

Catch ex As MySqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message, CType(MessageBoxIcon.Error, MsgBoxStyle), LoginUI.BrandMsgBox)

    DataConnection.Close()

End Try
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM borrowers WHERE ID=@BID` remove `*` character

Comment: @Fabio Thanks <3

Comment: Some flavours of SQL allow the wildcard in a `DELETE` statement but they generally allow it to be omitted as well. As you can't delete part of a record, I guess the MySQL authors decided to just allow one option for clarity and, as you can't specify individual columns, decided no wildcard was the more logical choice.